# Should DocBook be used for publishing technical documentation in English & Arabic?

Tags: pdf, publishing, arabic, docbook

I'm looking for the ideal tool to use for publishing technical documentation in English & Arabic (in the same document). Should I use DocBook, or is it better to stick with TeX/LaTeX? I am a complete beginner to both systems so there's no legacy stuff to worry about. The two most import factors for me are easy of use and support for Arabic. By ease of use I mean that I don't mind setting up XML documents or so on, but for day to day writing I'd rather not deal with hand-coding XML, a good editor that gives a feel for how the document sort of looks would be ideal. I would like the output to be print-ready PDF as well as HTML.

Comment: What did you use eventually? I looked at asciidoctor (http://asciidoctor.org/) but it doesn't support RTL languages yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, TeX/LaTeX in the [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) CD/DVD/bundle in the XeTeX incarnation is certainly able to deal with Arabic, see [these examples](http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/Demos/XeTeX-showcase/00Start-Here.html).  I'm not sure whether all the DocBook utilities (like the editors and things like fop) are up to this.

Comment: After a couple days of research it does look like LaTeX is the way to go... thanks.